# Photoshop(CC) Script that runs the action after the alert box appears

Tags: javascript, automation, photoshop-script, cc

I have a problem with the automation of processes in Photoshop (CC) and I hope that you can help me, or lead me where I could look for answers.

I created my own action in PS that processes the photo and adds various graphical elements (I called it working: Action A).

I have a lot of pictures so
I run the action using "Batch sequence ...".

Batch sequence opens the photo and launches "Action A". After time the alert box appears.

I can then choose "stop" and "continue".

At this point i need the second action (I called it working: Action B) to be activated when the dialogue box appears

I was looking for solutions in various forums and found only this:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1218184

Please help.

I greet Arthur

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your Action to a script and then use any conditional statement to decide what to do next.

For example, let's say your Action A has 10 steps and you want the 10th step to be a condition for deciding what to do next. You can convert your action to a script using the xbytor's ActionToScript script ([working link](https://github.com/Hennamann/CEP-Toolkit/blob/master/JSX%20Utility%20Scripts/ActionToJavascript.jsx)), in the resulting JSX file you'll find all your action steps converted to javascript code. You can use this file instead of your Action A or you can use only the part you need (10th step in my example), leaving all 9 previous steps as action steps and inserting the script as a last step.

Then in the script you can use `try..catch` or `if` statement to decide which action to play, for example this code is a command "Feather Selection" converted from Action. It tries to play, and if everything is fine, `Action B` from `My Actions` set will be played next. If it encounters an error (for example, there's no selection to feather), `Action C` will be played

```
function cTID(s){return app.charIDToTypeID(s);};
function sTID(s){return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);};

try
{
    var desc2285 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc2285.putUnitDouble(cTID('Rds '), cTID('#Pxl'), 5.000000);
    desc2285.putBoolean(sTID('selectionModifyEffectAtCanvasBounds'), false);
    executeAction(cTID('Fthr'), desc2285, DialogModes.NO);

    app.doAction("Action B", "My Actions");
}
catch (e)
{
    app.doAction("Action C", "My Actions");
}
```